# Rename static folder during build in react

Tags: reactjs, npm

I want to rename the "**static**" folder during "**npm run build**"
Is there any way to do that

Comment: Yes there probably is. But that would require more information about your build setup.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is not ejected, first you need to eject your app using [`npm run eject`](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/available-scripts/#npm-run-eject) command.

After that, you need to replace all `static/` text with `your_custom_static_folder_name/` in these 3 sections of `webpack.config.js` file:

for `js` folder:

```
filename: isEnvProduction
    ? "static/js/[name].[contenthash:8].js"
    : isEnvDevelopment && "static/js/bundle.js",
  // There are also additional JS chunk files if you use code splitting.
  chunkFilename: isEnvProduction
    ? "static/js/[name].[contenthash:8].chunk.js"
    : isEnvDevelopment && "static/js/[name].chunk.js",
  assetModuleFilename: "static/media/[name].[hash][ext]",
```

for `media` folder:

```
  {
              loader: require.resolve("file-loader"),
              options: {
                name: "static/media/[name].[hash].[ext]",
              },
            },
```

for `css` folder:

```
  isEnvProduction &&
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
      // both options are optional
      filename: "static/css/[name].[contenthash:8].css",
      chunkFilename: "static/css/[name].[contenthash:8].chunk.css",
    }),
```